# How to view a file in a cordova application?

Tags: cordova, plugins

I have a wsdl that returns the file as base64 string.I want to download that  file from my mobile app and view the file through PDF viewer or respective file viewer.I tired plugin like
cordova-plugin-file-transfer,cordova-plugin-file.

But I think Iam lacking in basic implementation steps of those plugin.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I believe file opener 2 can handle this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-opener2-base64

Install the plugin like this:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2
```

Sample usage:

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    filePath, //I think you can pass in a Base 64 string here e.g. data:image/png;base64,......... 
    fileMIMEType, 
    {
        error : function(){ }, 
        success : function(){ } 
    } 
);
```

Documentation here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-opener2-base64

Comment: Just an update: The fileOpener2 was not updated since 2 years now and fails to open files on Android 10 and higher. Due to their issues section, there is some hacky workaround availale, but it did not work for us. Seems there is no way around self developing a plugin for such basic functionality :-(